# Adding Entries into CalendarFX from Database

Tags: javafx

I am not sure how to add entries into the Calendar properly. I want to populate base on input from the data base.
I have tried the following but am unsure how to set the dates and entries. I am getting the data and placing into an ObserverableList . In my case the database table is CalendarData

```
 public class CalendarController<CalendarEvent> extends Application {


        private RosterService rosterService = new RosterServiceImpl();
        private ObservableList<CalendarData> calendarList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        public ObservableList<CalendarData> getCalendarDataList() {
            if (!calendarList.isEmpty())
                calendarList.clear();
            calendarList = FXCollections.observableList((List<CalendarData>) rosterService.listCalendarData());
            return calendarList;
        }




            @Override
            public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

                  CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(); 

                  Calendar shifts = new Calendar("ShiftRoster"); 

                  shifts.setStyle(Style.STYLE1); 


                  CalendarSource myCalendarSource = new CalendarSource("My Calendars"); 
                //  myCalendarSource.getCalendars().addAll(shifts, holidays);

                  calendarView.getCalendarSources().addAll(myCalendarSource); 

                  calendarView.setRequestedTime(LocalTime.now());
                  getCalendarDataList();      
                      for(CalendarData task : calendarList){
                         Entry<String> entry = new Entry<String>(task.getShiftType());
                         LocalDate date = task.getShiftDate();                      

                      shifts.addEntries(dates);
                      }

                      CalendarSource calendarSourceTasks = new CalendarSource("Shifts");
                      calendarSourceTasks.getCalendars().addAll(shifts);
                      calendarView.getCalendarSources().setAll(calendarSourceTasks);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by doing the following code:

```
CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView();
        Calendar shifts = new Calendar("ShiftRoster");
        shifts.setStyle(Style.STYLE1);
        ZoneId id = ZoneId.of("Australia/Brisbane");

        getCalendarDataList();
        for (CalendarData task : calendarList) {
            Entry<String> dentistAppointment = new Entry<>(task.getEmployeename());
            String startTime = task.getStartTIme();
            String endTime = task.getEndTime();
            LocalDate date = task.getShiftDate();
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss");
            LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse(startTime, dtf);
            LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse(endTime, dtf);
            if (!start.isAfter(end)) {
                dentistAppointment.setInterval(date);
                dentistAppointment.setInterval(start, end);
                shifts.addEntry(dentistAppointment);
            }
            if (!end.isAfter(start)) {
                dentistAppointment.setInterval(date);
                dentistAppointment.setInterval(date,start, date.plusDays(1),end);
                shifts.addEntry(dentistAppointment);
            }
        }

        CalendarSource calendarSourceTasks = new CalendarSource("Shifts");
        calendarSourceTasks.getCalendars().addAll(shifts);
        calendarView.getCalendarSources().setAll(calendarSourceTasks);
```

Comment: Changed dentistAppointment to shiftdetails in order to make more sense